# Efficiently join two labels of a DataFrame index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with one column of integers and string labels.
I want to join (as in sum up) two labels, while I replace the new label.

My DataFrame is:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([1,2,3,4]), index=['a','b','c','d'], columns=['cost'])

   cost
a     1
b     2
c     3
d     4
```

And I want to change it to:

```
         cost
a           1
b           2
c and d     7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know if there is a cleaner way but this works:

```
In [157]:

df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=['c and d'], data={'cost':df.loc[df.cost.isin([3,4])].sum().values})).drop(['c','d'])

Out[157]:
         cost
a           1
b           2
c and d     7
```

We construct a dataframe to append to your existing one. We set the new index to 'c and d', then sum those rows where the labels are in 'c' and 'd', then finally drop those.

Answer (score 2):

One option using `df.reindex`:

```
>>> df.loc['c and d'] = df.loc['c'] + df.loc['d']
>>> df.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c and d'])
>>> df
         cost
a           1
b           2
c and d     7

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: I think this is the clearest answer, mine is a bit obfuscated despite it being a one liner

Comment: Thanks - this is one of those questions which could have quite a few different answers. The most suitable method could well depend on what the rest of the data looks like and what the broader goals are!

Answer (score 0):

You could name the index labels of the one's you want summed and use a groupby.

```
In [35]: df = df.rename(index={'d': 'c'})

In [36]: df.groupby(level=0).sum()
Out[36]: 
   cost
a     1
b     2
c     7
```